# Getting token eof in power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

While trying to use a custom formula to find the sales' bonus for employees, I was using the following formula as it was shown in Microsoft's support video.

Bonus

= IF[Total_Sales]>25000 then [Total_Sales]*0.025 else 0.

However, in the second [Total_Sales], I am getting token eof, and can't apply the formula. Any suggestions as to what should I do?

P.S: I have started to learn about Power Query, and other Macro formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Is that exactly your formula?  If so you need to use the proper lower case on the if, and no ending period.  Powerquery is case-sensitive

```
IF[Total_Sales]>25000 then [Total_Sales]*0.025 else 0.
```

should be

```
if [Total_Sales]>25000 then [Total_Sales]*0.025 else 0
```

Comment: Did that solve your issue?